# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserModel (?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

When I try to use `MongooseModel` on `Users` I am getting the following error

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserModel (?). Please make sure
>   that the argument DatabaseConnection at index [0] is available in the
>   MongooseModule context.

**/src/database/database.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { databaseProviders } from './database.providers';
import { ConfigModule } from '../config/config.module';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  providers: [...databaseProviders],
  exports: [...databaseProviders],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

**/src/database/database.provider.ts**

```
// NPM Packages
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Provider } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

// Custom Packages
import { ConfigService } from '../config/config.service';

export const databaseProviders: Provider[] = [
  {
    inject: [ConfigService],
    provide: 'DATABASE_CONNECTION',
    useFactory: async (
      configService: ConfigService,
    ): Promise<typeof mongoose> =>
      await mongoose.connect(configService.get('MONGODB_URI'), {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
      }),
  },
];
```

**/src/app.module.ts**

```
// Core Packages
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

// NPM Packages

// Custom Packages
import { ConfigModule } from './config/config.module';
import { DatabaseModule } from './database/database.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule, DatabaseModule, AuthModule, UsersModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**/src/auth/auth.module.ts**

```
// Core Packages
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

// NPM Packages
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';

// Custom Packages
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { ConfigService } from 'src/config/config.service';
import { ConfigModule } from 'src/config/config.module';
import { DatabaseModule } from 'src/database/database.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    DatabaseModule,
    UsersModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        secret: configService.get('JWT_SECRET'),
        signOptions: { expiresIn: configService.get('JWT_EXPIRE') },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**/src/users/user.module.ts**

```
// Core Packages
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

// NPM Packages
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

// Custom Packages
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { UserSchema } from './schemas/user.schema';
import { DatabaseModule } from 'src/database/database.module';

@Module({
  providers: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }]),
  ],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of configuring mongoose statically in your `database.provider.ts`, you should use the `MongooseModule.forRootAsync` import:

```
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    uri: configService.getString('MONGODB_URI'),
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
});
```

Comment: Is there a way I can seperate out the configuration part into a new file and just import it on the `app.module.ts`

Comment: Yes, with `useClass`, see https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#async-configuration

Comment: tried it but not able to get it to work. Any suggestions? https://github.com/harshamv/nestjs-starter/blob/master/src/database/mongoose.config.service.ts

Comment: Maybe open a new question about it including the error message you receive. I'd say the problem of this thread is solved; this seems to be a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Passing module options asynchronously instead of statically helped.

you can use  **MongooseModule.forRootAsync** . Making changes in app.module.ts worked.

```
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        uri: 'mongodb://xxxxx',
      }),
    }),
   
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, *main.ts* was erroneously calling `NestFactory.create(UsersModule)` instead of `NestFactory.create(AppModule)`